# Recover data type in a PictureBOx

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm working on my first Chess Game. I create a list of PictureBox, and create a class for each piece like this:

```
public class Fou : PictureBox
{
    private ImageLayout ImageLayout;

    public Fou()
    {
        Image = Properties.Resources.pionnoir;
        this.ImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```

So now I have a picture in my PictureBox, but when I click on it I can't get the type of piece inside the PictureBox.

I would like to get the type, and use something like:

```
{
Fou pieceFou = new Fou();
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            if (pb == pieceFou) { pb.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite; }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: if typeof(Fou) == sender.GetType()

Comment: I'm assuming that the second code snippet is supposed to be the click handler?  How are you specifying the type of piece inside the PictureBox?

Comment: Inside de chessboard creation. 
But it's ok now. Thanks

Comment: It's working. The solution is `if typeof(Fou) == sender.GetType()`

Comment: I tried first, to declare a list of PictureBox, and assign just images on some PB depending on the type of piece. But it's seems more difficult this way to set pieces properties. Then I'm looking for another way to do it